# Can an Azure Pipeline use a template within a gated/approval stage?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I may be going about this the wrong way, but we currently have an `env-deploy-template.yaml` which contains some params such as the deployment environment name then a stage which runs our deployment jobs.

So something like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: DeployEnv
    type: string
    default: "Test"

stages:
  - stage: some-name
    displayName: "Deploy To ${{parameters.DeployEnv}}"
    variables:
      - group: "some-library.${{parameters.DeployEnv}}"
    jobs:
      - job: do-some-deployment-stuff
        displayName: "Do Some Stuff"
        steps:
          - task: ...
```

The usage of this in the main azure pipeline yaml looks like this currently:

```
trigger:
  - some-branch

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: "Build"
    jobs:
      - job: ...
  - template: env-deploy-template.yml
    parameters:
      DeployEnv: "Test"
      Name: "DeployToTest"
      
  - stage: RunAcceptanceTests
    dependsOn:
      - DeployToTest
    displayName: "Run Acceptance Tests"
    variables:
      - group: some-library.Test
    jobs:
      - job: RunAcceptanceTests
        displayName: "Run Acceptance Tests"
        steps:
          - task: ...
```

At this point once we have automatically deployed to `Test` and acceptance tests have been ran and verified we want to have an approval step for someone in test to sign it off, then have the next step run the same template but deploy to `UAT` for example.

The azure docs say config for an approval stage looks something like:

```
jobs:
- deployment: DeployToUAT
  displayName: "Deploy To UAT"
  dependsOn: DeployToTest
  environment: "uat" # assuming an environment exists in azure for uat with someone set up as an approver
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps: ...
```

The problem here is I do not want to run some steps within here I want it to run the `env-deploy-template.yaml` with some different params that target the `UAT` environmental config etc.

So is there a way to tell the above deploy section that it shouldn't do steps and instead should just go and run the template? or am I going about it all wrong and instead I should have another job after this which depends upon the above gated deployment section and that then runs the template?

I cannot find any examples online of people using templates here, and I assume this must be possible, so any help would be great.

Comment: I don't really understand what the difficulty is here. Make your `job` into a `deployment` job and organize it however you'd like. Steps, jobs, and stages can all be templated and imported using the exact same `- template` syntax you're already familiar with.

Comment: @DanielMann can you possibly post this as an answer with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following what difficulty you're experiencing. You should be able to turn `- job: do-some-deployment-stuff` into `- deployment: do-some-deployment-stuff`, and make the appropriate updates to add the additional parameters a deployment job requires, such as `environment`.

i.e.

```
stages:
  - stage: some-name
    displayName: "Deploy To ${{parameters.DeployEnv}}"
    variables:
      - group: "some-library.${{parameters.DeployEnv}}"
    jobs:
      - deployment: do-some-deployment-stuff
        environment: ${{parameters.DeployEnv}}
        displayName: "Do Some Stuff"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: ...
```

Comment: The main problem is I dont know where the `- template` bit should fit in, as its unclear from the azure docs. It is a stage within there, but the deployment bit has no stages, only jobs seem to.

Can you not post a succinct yaml example so myself and anyone else who is confused about how to do it (As the azure docs do not show any of these use cases).

Comment: Ah ok so you were talking about putting the environmental check within the template, I cant do that here though as the first time the template is used it does not depend upon an environment/approval gate, this being said I can potentially make a dummy environment with no gating that is referenced.

Comment: @Grofit That's how it works: You create an "Environment" in the Azure DevOps portal, assign checks and approvals to it, then reference it within your YAML. You can also put the same checks in place on repositories, service connections, and several other resources. A pipeline can't use a resource that has a check in place on it without the conditions being satisfied first.